# Possible to run ActiveRecord "each" block inside EventMachine periodic timer without blocking?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, eventmachine

I'd like to perform a batch database query for a large data set using ActiveRecord inside EventMachine. I'd like each call of the block passed to find_each to be called within an EventMachine periodic timer.

With the following, the find_each simply runs, and the add_periodic_timer block only runs once until the find_each is completely finished (i.e. the periodic timer block doesn't run every 0.001 seconds):

```
EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(0.001) do
  TradingCore::Quote.by_date(@date).by_symbols(@symbols).order(:created_at).find_each do |quote|
    ...
    sleep(delay) 
  end
end
```

Is there any way to make the find_each block execute for each record without blocking the event loop?

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved this using a fiber. So, I did this

```
quotes_fiber = Fiber.new {
  TradingCore::Quote.by_date(@date).by_symbols(@symbols).order(:created_at).find_each do |quote|
    ...
    sleep(delay) 

    Fiber.yield
  end
}

EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(0.001) do
  quotes_fiber.resume
end
```

and things seem to work fine :)